# Can't profile my maven project. Is there an error in my pom.xml file?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, pom.xml

I use Netbeans 8.2 with integraded Maven Support.
I can run my Project sucessfully but as soon as I try to Profile my project i get an error.

```
--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ MavenProject ---
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Unrecognized option: -createjar
```

I didn't change my POM File so I'm not sure why this error occurs.

I tried commenting -createjar argument but it showed the same error with the nocss2bin argument. I think something about the exec path must be wrong.

pom.xml file where -createjar is found:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack-dependencies</id>

            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>${java.home}/../bin/javapackager</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-createjar</argument>
                    <argument>-nocss2bin</argument>
                    <argument>-appclass</argument>
                    <argument>${mainClass}</argument>
                    <argument>-srcdir</argument>
                    <argument>${project.build.directory}/classes</argument>
                    <argument>-outdir</argument>
                    <argument>${project.build.directory}</argument>
                    <argument>-outfile</argument>
                    <argument>${project.build.finalName}.jar</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-cli</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>                            
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>${java.home}/bin/java</executable>
                <commandlineArgs>${runfx.args}</commandlineArgs>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>  
</plugin>
```

Comment: Any luck finding a solution to your problem? I am having the same issue, and am looking for help.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I switched to intellij idea some time ago

Comment: Thanks anyway ... I wish we could switch to IntelliJ